Suddenly losing UI after "Cannot find module .../page.js" and "Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

In NextJS v14, I'm loading a page and once in a while it just stops to render and function after showing these two error logs.
By referring to other threads, I can run rm -rf /.next that will temporarily fix this issue until the website crashes with the same format of error logs after 5min
 ✓ Compiled / in 7.6s (959 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 712ms (444 modules)
 ○ Compiling /dashboard ...
 ✓ Compiled /dashboard in 3.8s (1370 modules)
 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/.next/server/app/(routes)/dashboard/page.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:55:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at requirePage (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js:109:84)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:74:84
    at async loadComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:74:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:675:36) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js'
  ],
  page: '/dashboard'
}

<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/.next/server/app'
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Resolving '../../../../.next/server/app/not-found' in /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server for build dependencies doesn't lead to expected result '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/.next/server/app/not-found.js', but to 'Error: Can't resolve '../../../../.next/server/app/not-found' in '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server'' instead. Resolving dependencies are ignored for this path.
<w>  at resolve commonjs file ../../../../.next/server/app/not-found (expected /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/.next/server/app/not-found.js)
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-route-loader/index.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-route-loader/index.js
<w>  at resolve commonjs /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Quno/quno-os/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-route-loader/index.js

